# Pass parameters to Common.js from Aspx in .Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a web application with Common.js and it has the following function which is calling when this button **btnBookingStatus** was clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnBookingStatus', function () {

var req = new Object();
req.strMinNo = $(parent.document).find('#hdnFMinNo').val();
req.strSeqNo = $(parent.document).find("#hdnPSeqNo").val();
req.strUserId = $(parent.document).find("#hdnUserId").val();
if (req.strMinNo == undefined || req.strMinNo == '') {
    req.strMinNo = $(parent.document).find('#hdnMinNo').val();
}
if (req.strSeqNo == undefined || req.strSeqNo == '') {
    req.strSeqNo = $(parent.document).find('#hdnFinSeqNo').val();
}
if (req.strUserId == undefined || req.strUserId == '') {
    req.strUserId = $(parent.document).find('#hdnCurrentUserId').val();
}  
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(req),
    url: "../Common/LibUiUtilities.aspx/fnCreamsBookingStatus",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var retData = JSON.parse(data.d);
            if (retData.oRetunStatus == 'P' || retData.oRetunStatus == 'null') {
                alert("Creams Booking still in progress...");
            }
            else {
                $(parent.document).find('#drpBookingStatus').removeAttr('disabled');
                $(parent.document).find('#drpBookingStatus').val(retData.oRetunStatus);
                $(parent.document).find('#drpBookingStatus').attr('readonly', true);
                alert("Creams Booking Success");
            }
            if (retData.oReturnMsg != undefined && retData.oReturnMsg != 'null') {
                $(parent.document).find('#lblBkWarningMsg').text(retData.oReturnMsg);
            } else {
                $(parent.document).find('#lblBkWarningMsg').empty();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

There are 5 client windows with the same **btnBookingStatus** button with the same functionality, which needs to be called the above-mentioned JS function. But the hidden field names which pass the parameters are different.

```
    For eg:-
Form1.aspx --> hdnFMinNo, hdnFSeqNo
Form2.aspx --> hdnPMinNo, hdnPSeqNo
Form3.aspx --> hdnMinNo, hdnSeqNo
```

**These element Ids can not be changed**

I wanted to pass the parameters (MIN_NO and SEQ_NO) from ASPX to the Common.js without accessing the parent window's elements.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Have you try to add hidden input and set from aspx?

Comment: Yes. The fields mentioned above are hidden fields (hdnFMinNo, hdnFSeqNo, etc...) But the IDs of those fields are different from form to form. And I can not change those IDs also. I'm investigating an alternative way rather than these hidden fields.